# The jQuery replace with is not working on a string in a Wordpress Plugin

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins

I am trying to replace a "p" element's text with a .replaceWith() jQuery method,
in a Wordpress Plugin,

```
<p class="wfs-pricing-option-label">Choose Price Option</p>,

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery("p.wfs-pricing-option-label").replaceWith("<h6>Size</h6>");

});
```

The JS is in a custom file, which I've checked to see if it is linked correctly and a simple document.write does show when used, I also changed the CSS styling of this element and it does respond to such change but I cannot change the text inside of it. I don't know what I'm doing wrong I've used this method before many times, it is simple and effective, but in this case it just wont work.

Site address: http://www.bernibeancoffee.com/order-online/

If you click on any product you can see the label saying Chose Price Option.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

The popup you try to modify appears in the DOM by Ajax request. Your code runs earlier on the page load, so there is nothing to replace.

Try this:

```js
jQuery( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
  jQuery("p.wfs-pricing-option-label").replaceWith("<h6>Size</h6>");
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, just had to switch the first $ sign in the script you gave me here, but it worked like a charm. I never occurred to me it could be an ajax related issue. Thanks again.